# Pass props to a generic styled component in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to make a generic component using styled components which will accept the styling properties as props. IN my case it will be a Card which will have title, avatar, name, badge and other stuff.

I want each of the element to have style prop which can be done and that something I know but how do I pass props for hover and active state stylings ?

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-mendel-lismke?file=/src/App.tsx

I want a different background on hover, I've tried but that's not working, how do I achieve that ?

Edit: Also I want to show a different background color when card is clicked and it will remain the same unless the user toggles

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding styles from "styled components" with your `style` attribute.

```
<StyledCard style={props.cardStyle} // <-- don't use this with styled-components
```

You can use one or the other but don't mix them. When using styled components, pass the styles instead:

```
<StyledCard {...props}>
```

and define your styled-component as:

```
const StyledCard = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(props: CardProps) => props.cardStyle.background};
  width: ${(props: CardProps) => props.cardStyle.width}px;
  height: ${(props: CardProps) => props.cardStyle.height}px;
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${(props: CardProps) => props.hoverBackground};
  }
`;
```

You can see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-lovelace-uv165z?file=/src/Card.tsx) for reference.